# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Calendar'

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

I have code that allows a user to click on a calendar and it will output the date. I want to link the date to a sql query, but have the error:

```
File "C:\Users\dansi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\gui test 3.py", line 293, in datefunction
agro = int(agro)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Calendar'
```

Code in question:

```
def datefunction(self,agro):
    print(agro)
    agro = int(agro)
    agro = datetime.datetime(agro)
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(agro,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    print(list1)

def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
    """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
    agro = self.selection
    print(self.selection, self.datefunction())
    print(agro)
```

Lets say the user clicked on the 3rd of March, it would output

```
'2017-03-03 00-00-00'
```

How would be able to overcome the error?

Comment: Your `datefunction` has no `self` nor do you give it an `agro`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for some reason it does on my code but not on here

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand what you say.

Comment: you should also *call* your code with `self.datefunction(agro)`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem [That's what I said...](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36032089#36032089)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `datefunction` has one argument `agro`. But since it is an instance function, the `self` is bounded to `agro`. You can solve it with:

```
def datefunction(self,agro):
    print(agro)
    agro = int(agro)
    agro = datetime.datetime(agro)
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(agro,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    print(list1)

def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
    """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
    agro = self.selection
    print(self.selection, self.datefunction(agro))
    print(agro)
```

**EDIT**:

If you only want the date, you can modify the code to:

```
def datefunction(self,agro):
    print(agro)
    agro = int(agro)
    agro = datetime.datetime(agro).date()
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Date = (?)''',(agro,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    print(list1)

def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
    """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
    agro = self.selection
    print(self.selection, self.datefunction(agro))
    print(agro)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Don't know if this is the right place, but is there a way I can have only the date, and not the time?

Comment: @simons21: you can call `.date()` on the `.datetime(agro)` object.